# Getting lean angle from gyroscope and accelerometer wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, accelerometer, gyroscope

I want to calculate the lean angle when I ride my motorcycle at a track and think about using my lumia 920 for that. The product that got my interest was http://leanometer.com . I found out that using only a gyroscope is bad as it will drift over time so using a complementary filter with the accelerometer seemed the way to go. I found this code for doing this from http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/11:

```
#define ACCELEROMETER_SENSITIVITY 8192.0
#define GYROSCOPE_SENSITIVITY 65.536

#define M_PI 3.14159265359      

#define dt 0.01                         // 10 ms sample rate!    

void ComplementaryFilter(short accData[3], short gyrData[3], float *pitch, float *roll)
{
    float pitchAcc, rollAcc;               

    // Integrate the gyroscope data -> int(angularSpeed) = angle
    *pitch += ((float)gyrData[0] / GYROSCOPE_SENSITIVITY) * dt; // Angle around the X-axis
    *roll -= ((float)gyrData[1] / GYROSCOPE_SENSITIVITY) * dt;    // Angle around the Y-axis

    // Compensate for drift with accelerometer data if !bullshit
    // Sensitivity = -2 to 2 G at 16Bit -> 2G = 32768 && 0.5G = 8192
    int forceMagnitudeApprox = abs(accData[0]) + abs(accData[1]) + abs(accData[2]);
    if (forceMagnitudeApprox > 8192 && forceMagnitudeApprox < 32768)
    {
    // Turning around the X axis results in a vector on the Y-axis
        pitchAcc = atan2f((float)accData[1], (float)accData[2]) * 180 / M_PI;
        *pitch = *pitch * 0.98 + pitchAcc * 0.02;

    // Turning around the Y axis results in a vector on the X-axis
        rollAcc = atan2f((float)accData[0], (float)accData[2]) * 180 / M_PI;
        *roll = *roll * 0.98 + rollAcc * 0.02;
    }
}
```

I have converted this code to c# but I have problems to get something accurate with this. One thing is that I do not know the gyro/accelerometer sensitivity or how to get it. After a while I started to google some more on acclerometer and angle and found this: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/accelerometer-info which is a bit different from the angle above from the accelerometer but it seemed to work. When using the algorithm from hobbytronics and putting it into the code above I got a strange behavior so that it Always tried to get near -1.4 degrees angle.

I got the real code on Another computer but this is how I do it:

```
var lastReading = new DateTime();
var angleX = 0.0; 
var gyro = new Gyroscope();
gyro.TimeBetweenUpdates = 20ms;
gyro.CurrentValueChanged += ValueChanged;
var acc = new Accelerometer();
acc.TimeBetweenUpdates = 20ms;
gyro.Start(); acc.Start();

void ValueChanged(SensorReading reading)
{
    if(lastReading < 1 sec old)
    {
        var dt = lastReading - reading.Timestamp;
        if(reading.X > 0.05 || Reading.X < -0.05) // Got so much errors if I did not use this, maybe too high?
        {
           var x = reading.X * dt.TotalSeconds;
           var accData = acc.CurrentValue(); 
           var accX = atan(accData.X / Math.Sqrt(accData.Y*accData.Y+accData.Z*accData.Z));
           angleX = 0.98*(angleX + x *180 / Math.PI) + 0.02 * (accX *180 /Math.PI);
           TxtAngleX.Text = "x:" + angleX.ToString("F");
        }
    }
    lastReading = reading.Timestamp;
 }
```

What am I missing? One way to make it better could be to set the angle from accelerometer only, when the lastReading is older then one sec but I know that that is not the problem